# WebSocket closes for no apparent reason

Tags: java, websocket

Trying to use WebSockets. Connection from Client closes for no apparent reason. I've tracked it down to this line:

```
System.out.println("Will output");
UserSession session = gameServer.getConnectedUser(message.getReceptor());
System.out.println("Will not output");
session.getConnection().send(JSONEncoder.create(message));
```

Instead it immediately jumps to the onClose() of the WebSocket Server, although im doing absolutely nothing with the connection itself in the Line `UserSession session = gameServer.getConnectedUser(message.getReceptor());`

I then went to onClose() and added this:

```
System.out.println("Code: " + code + " reason: " + reason + " remote: " + remote);
Token token = getConnectedUser(conn).getToken();
scheduler.deleteFor(token);
Logger.logInfo("User " + token.toString() + " has quit");
```

"User xyz has quit" will get outputted, however the first System.out.println() will not get printed. Neither the reason, nor a code or anything else... What could cause such a connection close, and why is there no reason or code being given?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you simply aren't viewing sysout

Comment: @keyser: Then why does "Will output" a few secs earlier ouptut via System.out.println() ?

Comment: No idea. My first guess would be that some exception is messing with it

Comment: @keyser: However there is no single Exception being thrown, just nothing. The Connection simply closes which is outputted via the logger() and nothing else happens...